# Show/hide div onchange of drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I have the code for a dropdown menu in a form using haml

```
= f.select :contact_type, options_for_select(['String','Email','Phone','Textarea','Boolean', 'Multi Select'],
 selected: @contact_object.contact_type), onchange: "showDiv(this, @i)"
- if @contact_object.contact_type == 'Boolean'
  %div{:id=>"options_for_boolean_#{@i}"}
    %li
      =f.label :first_boolean_option do
        Field
        %span{:class => "item-number"}
          =@i
        First opt.
      =f.text_field :first_boolean_option, :placeholder => "Enter First option:"
    %li
      =f.label :second_boolean_option do
        Field
        %span{:class => "item-number"}
          =@i
        First opt.
      =f.text_field :second_boolean_option, :placeholder => "Enter Second option:"
- if @contact_object.contact_type == 'Multi Select'    
  %div{:id=>"options_for_multiselect_#{@i}"}
    %li
      =f.label :multiselect_options do
        Field
        %span{:class => "item-number"}
          =@i
        Multiselect opt.
      =f.text_area :multiselect_options, :placeholder => "Enter all options separated with comma:"
```

Here @i is the iterator value.
What I am trying to do here is, the above code is in a loop. Each loop has a drop down menu with selected value. When user selects Boolean or Multi select option, it will show him respective div for more details. So if a user chooses Boolean option of 2nd drop down box, it should show div for boolean in 2nd iterated layer. Confused? here is simpler explanation

```
drop-down-box1
  div1 for boolean
  div1 for multi select

drop-down-box2
  div2 for boolean
  div2 for multi select

drop-down-box3
  div3 for boolean
  div3 for multi select
```

*All divs are hidden by default. if a user selects "boolean" of "drop-down-box2", it should show "div2 for boolean"
 How to do it?

My jQuery code till now is

```
:javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  function showDiv(changing,numb) {
    var sel_val = changing.options[changing.selectedIndex].val();
    if (sel_val == 'Boolean') {
      $('#options_for_boolean_' + numb).show();
    } else if (sel_val == 'Multi Select') {
        $('#options_for_multiselect_' + numb).show();
    } else {
        $('#options_for_boolean_' + numb ).hide();
        $('#options_for_multiselect_'+ numb).hide();
    } 
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the actual outputted HTML? I'm not fluent in HAML

Comment: Ok, I have given a simpler explanation of what my question is, Please solve it
http://snipurl.com/24kjkbr
What I want is, when user selects "taffy" of 1st drop-down box, div #for_taffy_1 should be shown, Similarly when user selects "taffy" of 2nd drop down box, div #for_taffy_2 should be shown, How to do that in jquery or javascript

*NB: I have given only two sets. It is a loop, so can be many

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was in the haml code for select tag, **onchange event is not triggered properly**. we can call this issue as "**onchange html option is not appearing in the browser**".

This below concept helped me a lot.

:onchange is an html_option. Here's the syntax for select:

**

> select(object, method, choices, options={}, html_options={})

**

So in my case:

```
= f.select :contact_type, options_for_select(['String','Email','Phone','Textarea','Boolean', 'Multi Select'], selected: @contact_object.contact_type),{},
  :onchange => "showDiv(#{@i});"
```

Notice the empty hash in there to represent the options.
moreover, I changed my javascript code to this below

```
:javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
  function showDiv(numb) {
    var sel_val = $('#userservicepage_contactsettings_attributes_' + numb + '_contact_type').val();
    if (sel_val == "Boolean") {
      $('#options_for_boolean_' + numb).show();
    } else if (sel_val == "Multi Select") {
      $('#options_for_multiselect_' + numb).show();
    } else {
      $('#options_for_boolean_' + numb ).hide();
      $('#options_for_multiselect_'+ numb).hide();
    }
  }
});
```

As a result the whole thing become dynamic.